# Multiplayer Gaming with Head-Mounted Display (Microsoft) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, microsoft, us20110078554, head-mounted-display

US Patent Application: [US 20130196757 A1](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=20130196757.PGNR.&OS=DN/20130196757RS=DN/20130196757)

**TITLE: Multiplayer Gaming with Head-Mounted Display**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A method of inviting other playes to join you in a multiplayer game on head-mounted display (e.g. Google Glass).

- **Publication Number**: [US 20130196757 A1](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=20130196757.PGNR.&OS=DN/20130196757RS=DN/20130196757)
- **Application Number**: 13/361,798
- **Assignee**: [Microsoft, Inc.](http://www.microsoft.com)
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** Jan 30, 2012

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to the Jan 30, 2012.

**"Inviting users to multiplayer games with head-mounted display” from Microsoft**

[image]

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method for inviting a potential player to participate in a multiplayer game with a user, the multiplayer game displayed by a display of a user head-mounted display device, comprising:
>
> 1. receiving user voice data from the user;
> 2. determining that the user voice data is an invitation to participate in the multiplayer game;
> 3. receiving eye-tracking information, depth information, facial recognition information, potential player head-mounted display device information, and/or potential player voice data;
> 4. associating the invitation with the potential player using the eye-tracking information, the depth information, the facial recognition information, the potential player head-mounted display device information, and/or the potential player voice data;
> 5. matching a potential player account with the potential player;
> 6. receiving an acceptance response from the potential player; and
> 7. joining the potential player account with a user account associated with the user in participating in the multiplayer game.

In English this means:

> A method for inviting a potential player to participate in a multiplayer game which is displayed on a head-mounted display (e.g. two users using Google Glass):
>
> 1. First user invites a second user to a multiplayer game with his voice
> 2. Recognizing the second player using face recognition, voice, device information, etc.
> 3. Matching a player account with the second user
> 4. Receiving an acceptance to play from the second user; and
> 5. Letting the two accounts participate in the multiplayer game together

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

Answer (score 1):

This might have been anticipated by https://www.google.com/patents/WO2010141870A1 "3d video processor integrated with head mounted display" :

> "**ABSTRACT** 
>   A 3-D stereo video device that includes a headset housing
>   that incorporates a 3-D video processor chip, video display driver
>   circuitry, micro-displays and optics such that the only required
>   external component is a joystick or other user input device. By
>   utilizing a direct digital video interface between the video processor
>   chip and the video driver chip, the need for video signal
>   encoder/decoders, digital to analog converters, video up-converters
>   and other similar complicated circuitry to handle remotely generated
>   analog video signals are eliminated. The design not only saves cost
>   but also allows for a higher resolution, higher frame-rate video
>   presentations than previous designs."

from the **BACKGROUND**:

> "Head-mounted displays are sometimes used in products such as
>   electronic games. For example, a game known as i-Combat™ from a
>   company called Radica Games and a product such as the Virtual Boy™
>   from Nintendo date from the mid- 1990's time-frame. These games used
>   low quality displays of varying types implemented, for example, with
>   Light Emitting Diode (LED) technology and an oscillating mirror system
>   to present the image. These devices also had various types of
>   connected controllers and game cartridge interfaces."

Answer (score 1):

**America's Army: Special Forces (Overmatch)** from 2007 with TrackIR headset support and voice activation control (VAC) provides at least a partial match. According to this 2007 review: http://www.ausgamers.com/files/details/html/30505

> Voice Activation Control
>   VAC enables players to use the America's Army voice recognitions system to issue commo commands and initiate actions. **Now players have the ability to speak the radio command they want rather than cycling through menus.** You can also map any key to a voice command to customize your AA experience.
>
> ...
>
> TrackIR Headset Support
>   Support for the TrackIR Virtual Reality Headset has been improved. Players with this hardware can now use the system in the HMMWV for enhanced gameplay. (TrackIR hardware required.)

A complete listing of command mappings for VAC is here:
http://archive.forum.americasarmy.com/viewtopic.php?t=263918 
It includes the command Choose Team:

```
<P PROPNAME="SELECTTEAM">Choose Team</P>
```

This suggests that VAC combined with the headset could be used to choose a team member, thereby inviting them to the game, which matches the patent claim. Further input from someone familiar with the game and these accessories would be needed.